# How can I split a text using split by lines?

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am trying to split data by lines, using the method split. This is the code i am trying to use but i can't figure out what to use for the parameters of .split(). This is how the data will be in the txt.

```
19
23
58
49


Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("random.txt")); 
string line = sc.nextLine(); 
String[] numbers = line.split(" "); 
int nums = new int[numbers.length]; 
for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) 
nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
```

The end goal is so that the data can be put into an array, not to just print it.

Comment: Have you tried using `$`?

Comment: Just tried it, it did not work

Comment: But you're currently reading line by line, so you would have the data already split by lines... What's your exact problem?

Comment: I am trying to get information stored into an array, but even when i use sc.next() instead of sc.nextLine i still can't get it to split, It will only use the first character or the first slot in the array.

Comment: @Renuz You're reading the file **line by line** with a `Scanner`. You have exactly one number from the file in `line`

Comment: @Renuz - do you want to read the file like in question and load the data into array ?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use split if you have only one number in each line.

just use the following

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:/projects/random.txt"));
        while( sc.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use it like this:

> Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("random.txt"));
>
> int[] nums;
>
> int i=0;
>
> while(sc.hasNext()){
>
> ```
> String line = sc.nextLine(); 
>
> nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
>
> i++;
> ```
>
> }

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just as simple as that, you don't need `split` since you're reading line by line as [@Luiggi Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993727/how-can-i-split-a-text-using-split-by-lines#comment35116839_22993727) said

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:/projects/random.txt"));
while( sc.hasNext()){
    nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]); //They're stored in here
    i++;
}
int max = i; //To keep length of numbers that have been read
for(i = 0; i < max; i++){
    System.out.println(nums[i]); //We print them from the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while(true){
        int tmp=line.indexOf(" ");
        if(tmp==-1)
            break;
        System.out.println(ar[i]);
        ar[i++]=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,tmp));
        line =line.substring(tmp+1);    
    }
```